# Custom ordering of groups within a CollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, grouping

I'm trying to find a way of ordering groups within a CollectionViewSource and display them along with ungrouped items within a XAML DataGrid. I'm currently creating the CVS from an ObservableCollection and assigning the grouping description, which is a property of the objects in the collection.

I know that I could be sorting them as ascending/descending, but what I'm interested is in being able to rearrange the DataGrid as it was a media playlist with grouping functionality.

Any ideas on how this should work would be *greatly appreciated*.

Update: [ListCollectionView.CustomSort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.customsort.aspx) exposes an IComparer interface to sort items, but how could that be wired to its position?

Current code:

> ViewModel

```
 ObservableCollection<PlaylistItem> Playlist { get; set; }
 CollectionViewSource CVS { get; set; }
 //
 Playlist = new ObservableCollection<PlaylistItem>();
 CVS = new CollectionViewSource{ Source = Playlist };
 CVS.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group"));
 CVS.IsLiveGroupingRequested = true;
```

> View

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CVS.View}">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MultiItemGroupTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander IsExpanded="False" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" Background="White">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SingleItemGroupTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Style.Resources>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SingleItemGroupTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MultiItemGroupTemplate}"/>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>

            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
 </DataGrid>
```